# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de un formulario en Hubspot a otro en html?

Tags: html5

Es la primera vez que escribo en este foro, espero hacerlo correctamente. A continuación paso a comentar mi problema.

Tengo un formulario realizado en HubSpot y quiero que los datos que se introducen en este formulario se queden reflejados en otro formulario externo que esta realizado en HTML.

¿Saben alguna forma de como puedo hacer este traspaso de datos entre HubSpot y una página html?.

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: ¿Las dos paginas son tuyas?

Comment: Si que son mias solo que una esta hecha en Hubspot y la otra en una plataforma HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante javascript, puedes hacer una llamada asíncrona (ajax) y enviar los datos a la pagina que recibiría el formulario de tu "plataforma html".

Usando el framework de javascript JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), quedaría algo como esto:

```
<html>

    <form id="formulario_HubSpot">    
        <div><label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" name="nombre" /></div>
        <div><label>Contaseña:</label><input type="text" name="contrasena" /></div>
        <input type="submit" id="boton_enviar" name="enviar"/>   
    </form>    

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#boton_enviar").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.miservidor.es/procesar_formulario.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    jsonp : 'callback',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: $("#formulario_HubSpot").serialize(),
                })
                        .done(function (data) {
                            console.log("Respuesta:", data);

                        });
            });
        })
    </script>

</html>
```

Este forma de operar no está exenta de complicaciones y riesgos de seguridad, yo personalmente prefiero usar una llamada cURL (http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) desde el servidor, pero como no explicas el contexto del problema y solo has añadido el tag HTML5, es complicado darte opciones o soluciones con un lenguaje específico.

Información adicional: 
https://geeks.ms/jalarcon/2009/09/26/jsonp-llamadas-ajax-a-servidores-remotos/

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Creo que si que nos puede ayudar a realizar lo que queremos.